# angular-country-select module not selecting default value

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2

I am using [angular-country-select](https://github.com/alexcheng1982/angular-country-select) module.
I am not able to set the default selected value to the dropdown.

```
<input country-select data-ng-model="userCtrl.country" class="signup-country" placeholder="Country*" ng-required="true" name="country" id="signUpCountry" value="{{userCtrl.country}}">
```

I tried to modify the module code to pass the val to select2 (as this module used select2). Below is the modified code:

```
angular.module('angular-country-select', [])
.directive('countrySelect', [function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require:'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) { console.log("elem");
    var data = ["id":"AX","text":"Åland Islands"},{"id":"AL","text":"Albania"}, ....]; //This array has values
    var defaultValue = attrs.value || '';
      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(defaultValue);
    var select2Inst = elem.select2({
      data: data,
      val: defaultValue
    });
  }
};
```

}]);

But this also does not select the default value.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to select the default by adding $timeout
Below is updated module code:

```
angular.module('angular-country-select', [])
.directive('countrySelect', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require:'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) { console.log(attrs, attrs.placeholder);
    var data = [{"id":"AF","text":"Afghanistan"},{"id":"AX","text":"Åland Islands"},...];
    var select2Inst = elem.select2({
      data: data
    });
    $timeout(function() {
      if (attrs.value != '') {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(attrs.value);
        scope.$apply(select2Inst.select2('val', attrs.value));
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
};
}]);
```